# Join-Path AdditionalChildPath parameter deprecated or am I misusing?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to use `Join-Path` to join a path with 4 subpaths:

```
path1 = "Users"
path2 = "Bob"
path3 = "Documents"
path4 = "project"
```

So that when the paths are joined it becomes:

```
Users/Bob/Documents/project
```

I have looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters) and I see Example 7 provided that's using `AdditionalChildPath`:

```
Join-Path a b c d e f g

a\b\c\d\e\f\g
```

but when I try:

```
Join-Path $a $b $c $d
```

I get this error:

```
Join-Path : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AdditionalChildPath'.
```

Alternatively I have tried all these:

```
Join-Path -Path $a -ChildPath $b -AdditionalChildPath ($c $d)
Join-Path -Path $a -ChildPath $b -AdditionalChildPath $c $d
Join-Path -Path $a -ChildPath $b -AdditionalChildPath [$c $d]
```

and they all give the same aforementioned error.

Does someone have a suggestion for what I may be doing wrong? Is the `AdditionalChildPath` parameter deprecated? It appears in the documentation, so I assume it can't be deprecated. I understand I could pipe it into multiple `Join-Path` commands but I'd rather not.

Comment: I'm betting that it's the opposite of the parameter being depreciated, I'm guessing that it didn't exist until a newer version of PowerShell than what you're running. That parameter didn't exist until PowerShell v6, are you using v6 or above?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician is correct; the linked duplicate should explain the details. Generally, use  `-?` (`Join-Path -?`) from inside a PowerShell session to see the actual syntax for your version; `Get-Help Join-Path` and `Get-Help -Online Join-Path` too should provide version-specific help. If you google just the cmdlet name, you're taken to the _most recent_ (officially released) PowerShell version's page instead, but there's a version drop-down list above the list of topics on the left that allows you to view the topic for an earlier version / preview version.

Comment: As an aside re syntax: in v6+, with _positional_ arguments, you specify all path components as _individual_ arguments: `Join-Path $a $b $c $d`. By contrast, if you do want to use a _named_ argument for the additional components, you must pass them _as an array_: `Join-Path $a $b -AdditionalChildPath $c, $d`

Comment: Thank you @TheMadTechnician this was it! I had downloaded two versions of powershell, one being lower than v6 and was unknowingly using that. I used the v7 version and now it works :)

Comment: Thank you @mklement0 I didn't know which syntax for listing those additional child paths as an array was correct or if multiple were correct/worked, so that's really helpful.